# GridView as a header for a ListView android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

Can we use gridView as a header to a listView? 
The gridView only display one row and skips the other rows. Where as the listView is working fine.
This is header xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label" 
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the fragment_main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code that i use to setAdapters

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
   mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list); 

        //header on each fragment
        View headerView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_header, null);

        mTextView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        mTextView.setText("Title");

        mGridView = (GridView) headerView
                .findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter( mThumbIds , getActivity().getApplicationContext() ));

        mListView.addHeaderView(headerView); 
        //header on each fragment

        mTaskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listview_row, data);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       }
```

Comment: yes you can set  are you getting any error  ?

Comment: Yes the gridView display only one row and skips the other rows

Comment: i have tried fill_parent and match_parent and wrap_content at height of the gridView as well but still the problem persists

Comment: set height of Layout like 50dp .... and check

Comment: it does not solve the problem

Comment: @mushahid Have you solved this problem?

Comment: no, i tried a lot but nothing worked and sorry for the late reply bro. What problem are you facing maybe i can help if i know what problem you are facing